# How to show object values in HTML persistently

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's suppose I am having an object like `y={1,2,3}`. I want to display its value using Angular in HTML.

So what I did is:

```
for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++){
      $scope.data=y[i]; //transferring
}
```

and in my HTML it is written:

```
   <html>
      {{data}}
   </html>
```

Now I know that it is showing the last value(3) because the data value is updated at the end, and since the last value of the loop is 3 it sets the 3 in HTML. So my question is how can we fix this problem?

Comment: Update your question. It seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that `y` should be an array:

```
var y = [1, 2, 3]
```

Second, you should use `ng-repeat` in your html, not for loop:

```
<span ng-repeat="num in y">
    {{ num }}
</span>
```

Most importantly, you should look through the documentation and some tutorials first. Because it is the most basic part of angularjs which is taught first in every book or tutorial.

**UPDATE**

If you want to show object properties in your html, you can do this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in y">
    {{key}} - {{ value }}
</span>
```

Comment: lol no.I know what to do if it is in array.What I want is to display a value which is coming in object format.Hence the question is complete.

Comment: Well, objects don't look like this: {1, 2, 3}! They look like this: {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
        if(Auth.getCurrentUser()._id==val[i].values[0].custid){
          $scope.data=val[i].values[0];
          console.log(val[i].values[0]);
        }
      }

Comment: This is my situation.I gotta repeatedly send the values and want every value to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I got the answer!
Store every response in an array and then render that array using ng-repeat.
It was so easy that it dint scratched my mind.